# How to avoid stalled scp transfer when tunneling through a gateway over ssh?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, file-transfer, scp, tunneling

I'm try to transfer a large (1GB+) file from one machine to another, but I have to [tunnel through a gateway](http://www.noah.org/wiki/SSH_tunnel#Using_scp_through_a_DMZ_gateway_to_a_machine_behind_a_firewall_using_a_tunnel) in between. I'm able to transfer small files just fine. However, with the big file, the transfer stalls mid-way through.

After reading a [blog post on the stalling scp transfers](http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1371), I tried using `-l 8192` and even tried lowering it to `-l 2000`, but that just seemed to make it stall sooner:

```
scp -l 2000 -v -P 2222 username@localhost:/path/to/file.gz .
```

From the verbose output (`-v`) of the scp command, it look like the `-l` isn't getting passed on…

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f -- /path/to/file.gz
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: `-l` shouldn't be passed on. It's a local option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ugly work around would be to use `rsync` instead of `scp`. The `rsync` program can reliably resume interrupted transfers. If it hangs, just break out with `CTRL-C` and repeat the command.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `rsync` in a `screen` session. An interrupt can be re-run with `--ignore-existing` option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rsync is an ugly work around.  Be sure to use the -c flag rsync, that way it can pick up where it left off if the connection gets interupted, also include the --verbose to see more info during the transfer.